# CSS3 scale not working

Tags: css

I am very new to web development and I can't seem to be able to scale my text. I've tried to look up how but my search has always come up empty.

```css
#top-nav {
    background: #94b3c8;
    text-align: cemter;
}

#top-nav dt {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font: 20px Tahoma;
    color: white;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}

#top-nav a:active {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#top-nav a:link {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#top-nav a:visited {
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#top-nav a:hover {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
    transform: scale(1.5, 1.5)
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5)
    -webkit-transform: scale (1.5, 1.5)
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5)
    -o-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5)
}
```

Comment: You should put `transform: scale(1.5,1.5);` below the prefixed transforms for when a browser previously supporting a prefix only adds support for the standard, you don't have to update your code. It will start using the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add semi-colons after your `transform` definitions, otherwise the browser will see that as an error and will ignore the subsequent rules.

```
transform: scale(1.5, 1.5); /*you didn't have the semi-colons here*/
-ms-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
-webkit-transform: scale (1.5, 1.5);
-moz-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
-o-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I can't believe i missed that.

Comment: @JackJenkins If this fixed your issue, don't forget to "tick" this answer as accepted!